# How can I decompose intersecting types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to decompose *intersecting types* in TypeScript? YES, I know it can be done with union types, but I don't think I can use `Exclude<,>` on interesting types (I tried that already and it doesn't work). Example:

File1.ts - My system file.

```
namespace A {
   class $PrivateTypeA { }
   export var TypeA: typeof $PrivateTypeA & { Func(a:string):any } = <any>$PrivateTypeA;
}
```

File2.ts - Some other developer using my file.

```
namespace B {
   class $PrivateTypeB extends <Exclude<typeof A.TypeA, Func(a:any)=>any>><any>A.TypeA { } // (YES, I know this won't work, but it gives you the idea)
   export var TypeB: typeof $PrivateTypeB & { Func(a:number):any } = <any>$PrivateTypeB;
}
```

The goal is to:

1. NOT expose the private class types directly (I don't want code completion to pick them up).
2. Strip out the added type from the exported value so I can get back the original type (otherwise, the different signatures of `Func` will stack).
3. Of course, after decomposing the type, I need the original type, including all constructor signatures if any.

Yes, there are plenty of workarounds, such as storing the original type in another property (just add `& {__originalType: typeof $TheType}`), or using `exclude<,>` on property names and rebuilding the type signature while losing the original constructor signatures,  but that's not what I'm looking for.  I just want to know if it can be done, and how, or just say no. ;) I’m hoping I’m missing something new in the latest versions that I’m not aware of (I went through the release notes and only `exclude` comes close, but it only seems to work on union types). I'm open to other ideas also, but the points 1-3 must be met.

Comment: `TypeA` is just an instance of `$PrivateTypeA` ? or is it supposed to be the class itself augmented with a static method `Func` ?

Comment: Yeah, this is confusing.  Reiterating @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's comment:  You can't even write `class $PrivateTypeB extends A.TypeA` because `A.TypeA` isn't a class constructor.   Is `TypeA` supposed to be a class constructor?  Is `Func` supposed to be a static method or an instance method?

Comment: Sorry made a mistake, clarified it.

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to be able to inspect overloaded function types, including overloaded constructors.  So you can add back in one constructor signature but it's not necessarily the same as the original.  So the answer is probably "no" if your requirements are that strict.  Maybe file a suggestion or feature request?

Comment: I had a feeling as well, thanks.